# The program can be found in the following packages

Tags: nodejs, maven-3

When i write `mvn` command in Terminal i get this message:

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I also get the same message for `node` command:

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Which i think means that i have two version of maven installed and 
for `node` i have another program besides nodejs which also has `node` command associated with it.

So it wants me to use:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

To permanently associate `mvn` command with one of the programs (versions of `maven`) `maven` or `maven2`.

Now is there a way to temporarily use `mvn` for `maven` or for `maven2`? 
I mean a way that I can select one of `maven` or `maven2` temporarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The command `mvn`

In the case of `mvn`, you can install `maven` (v3, *not* v1) and `maven2` (v2) side by side with:

```
sudo apt-get install maven maven2
```

and you will have two binaries.

```
/usr/share/maven/bin/mvn
/usr/share/maven2/bin/mvn
```

To switch between the two binaries, use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
```

*Example*

```
% mvn -version 
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-17)
Java version: 1.8.0_45
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.19.0-22-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"

% sudo update-alternatives --config mvn
There are 2 choices for the alternative mvn (providing /usr/bin/mvn).

  Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/maven2/bin/mvn   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn    150       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/maven2/bin/mvn   200       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn to provide /usr/bin/mvn (mvn) in manual mode


% mvn -version                         
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-22-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

---

### The command `node`

In the case of `node`, that's not possible or only with greater effort:

```
% sudo apt-get install node nodejs-legacy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy but 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 nodejs-legacy : Conflicts: node but 0.3.2-7.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

It says you don't have installed that programs.
So you can install nodejs with:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

And install maven with:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```